# FormsSeekBar.setPressed. Exception of type 'Java.Interop.JavaLocationException' was thrown in xamarin.forms with Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, crash, visual-studio-app-center

I am developing app on android using xamarin forms. I am getting below issue.

Xamarin Exception Stack:

```
    System.NotSupportedException: Unable to activate instance of type Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsSeekBar from native handle 0x7fddf15d64 (key_handle 0x55481da).
  at Java.Interop.TypeManager.CreateInstance (System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer, System.Type targetType) [0x0017e] in <5029faf3775942b79c91624f8b49b012>:0
  at Java.Lang.Object.GetObject (System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer, System.Type type) [0x00023] in <5029faf3775942b79c91624f8b49b012>:0
  at Java.Lang.Object._GetObject[T] (System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x00017] in <5029faf3775942b79c91624f8b49b012>:0
  at Java.Lang.Object.GetObject[T] (System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x00000] in <5029faf3775942b79c91624f8b49b012>:0
  at Java.Lang.Object.GetObject[T] (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x00006] in <5029faf3775942b79c91624f8b49b012>:0
  at Android.Views.View.n_SetPressed_Z (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Boolean pressed) [0x00000] in <5029faf3775942b79c91624f8b49b012>:0
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.152(intptr,intptr,bool)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  System.MissingMethodException: No constructor found for Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsSeekBar::.ctor(System.IntPtr, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership)
    at Java.Interop.TypeManager.CreateProxy (System.Type type, System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer) [0x000b5] in <5029faf3775942b79c91624f8b49b012>:0
    at Java.Interop.TypeManager.CreateInstance (System.IntPtr handle, Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer, System.Type targetType) [0x00111] in <5029faf3775942b79c91624f8b49b012>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    Java.Interop.JavaLocationException: Exception of type 'Java.Interop.JavaLocationException' was thrown.
      at Java.Lang.Error: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Error' was thrown.
      at java.lang.Error: Java callstack:
      at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.FormsSeekBar.n_setPressed(Native Method)
      at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.FormsSeekBar.setPressed(FormsSeekBar.java:63)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSetPressed(ViewGroup.java:4509)
      at android.view.View.setPressed(View.java:10579)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSetPressed(ViewGroup.java:4509)
      at android.view.View.setPressed(View.java:10579)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSetPressed(ViewGroup.java:4509)
      at android.view.View.setPressed(View.java:10579)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSetPressed(ViewGroup.java:4509)
      at android.view.View.setPressed(View.java:10579)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSetPressed(ViewGroup.java:4509)
      at android.view.View.setPressed(View.java:10579)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSetPressed(ViewGroup.java:4509)
      at android.view.View.setPressed(View.java:10579)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSetPressed(ViewGroup.java:4509)
      at android.view.View.setPressed(View.java:10579)
      at android.view.View$UnsetPressedState.run(View.java:26395)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6702)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)

Thread 2:
0   dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(VMStack.java:-2)
1   java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1538)
2   java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Thread.java:1588)
3   com.microsoft.appcenter.crashes.Crashes.saveUncaughtException(Crashes.java:1140)
```

This crash continuously occurred in app center. We could not recreate this issue. Above Exception Stack occurred in app center. How to resolve the issue?

Comment: Could you provide more information for me to reproduce? Do you always get this issue?

Comment: This issue is most repeatedly occurred in the app center crash

Comment: im also having the same problem. please any help to to solve this issue

Comment: This crash continuously occurred in app center. We could not recreate this issue. Detailed Exception log mentioned in the post @WendyZang-MSFT